# c# provider for excel not registered

Tags: c#, excel, database, accessibility

For some projects I need the options of exporting and importing from/to an Excel.

For that I'm using that code:

```
        private void myButton12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = string.Empty;
            string ext = string.Empty;
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = file.FileName;
                ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);

                if(ext == ".xls" || ext == ".xlsx")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ok");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = ReadExcel(path, ext);

                    dataGridView13.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }

        public DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt)
        {
            string conn = string.Empty;
            DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
            if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
                conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"; //for below excel 2007  
            else
                conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 16.0;HDR=NO';"; //for above excel 2007  
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con); //here we read data from sheet1  
                    oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel); //fill excel data into dataTable  
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
            return dtexcel;
        }
```

Problem is that I get that Exception:

```
The provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is not registered on the local computer.
```

After looking on the internet, I seems like it come from the x86 configuration need that I tried... I've also tried switching for some others, but none of them worked,

I really can't find any solution to my problem,

Any idea where the problem can be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your app in X64 Target CPU  you need "AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe" , if you run your app in X86 you need "AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" fromthe page below :

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255